# Is there a security risk when using a user-inputted variable in sqlite3.connect()?

Tags: python, security, sqlite

I am having users both create and connect to a database through a python application,

```
           dbname = raw_input("Please enter the game name you wish to connect to, or the name of a new game: ")
           db = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
```

I'm curious: is there any kind of input a potentially malicious user could use to attack the database (providing I have no other vulnerabilities in the other handlers), or to attack the underlying system running python? (I am aware that a user could continue to create an infinite number of databases by running the program over and over, however I can't think of any other solution than quotas for that).

Thanks in advance!

Travis

Comment: All input is, until proven otherwise, (1) malicous, (2) willing to break your code, and (3) totally capable of doing so. (That said, this doesn't *look* like the typical security loophole.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can pass in `":memory"`, which may or may not have an adverse effect on the system, depending on what your application does.

They can [control transactions](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions) (via the `isolation_level` parameter), which might mess up your program's interaction with the database.

I would check user-input against a dictionary of possible database names.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't allow that.  Imagine what could happen if the user enters "Global Thermonuclear War"?

In all seriousness, you'll probably want to give the user a menu with IDs for example 1..5 associated with the games, then in your code use something like a switch case statement to establish the DB name to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the connections themselves are not something to worry about. It's any queries that can be malicious or destructive. Having a user enter the name of the database to connect to poses no security threat that I can see, but make sure yourqueries are risk-free from injection.

Answer (score 0):

> When in doubt sanitize the data because:

```
garbage in == garbage out
```

if user *inputs garbage* the program will most likely *output garbage*

To quote:

> All input is, until proven otherwise, (1) malicous, (2) willing to
>   break your code, and (3) totally capable of doing so. (That said, this
>   doesn't look like the typical security loophole.) – delnan

...

> Sanitize it by escaping, encoding, etc. Then check against a *whitelist*, not a *blacklist* (because it does not check for unknown dangers unlike a *whitelist*)